# What's a good tool to run a list of regex search-replace patterns against a text file?

Tags: regex, sed, textmate, bbedit

I want to invoke the tool via the Textmate 'Filter Through Command' command.

The intention is to replace the BBEdit 'Textfactory' functionality, as larger textfactories tend to become hard to manage.

Is sed the tool of choice? Any best practices on using it for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever you happen to know, sed, AppleScript, PHP, Perl, Ruby, any one of them will do the job if you already know how to use it. The best practice is to use the language you're comfortable with. One advantage of TextMate is that its extensibility is language independent.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a shell script that reads STDIN and prints to STDOUT. Use whatever language you know.